# GeoServer polygon transparency (SLD style file)

Tags: geoserver, polygon, sld, color, transparency-opacity

I am trying to add transparency to a set of polygons (city bounds) within a .sld style file for OSM.  Please see below:

[image: no transparnecy]

As you can see the city bounds are overlapping Montana State University.  My goal is to have no fill or transparent fill for the city bounds. In this image I have it set to `#00FFFFFF` and GeoServer is not liking it as you can see.

Here is the SLD chunk for the polygon:

```
<sld:Name>Boundary</sld:Name>
<sld:Title>Boundary</sld:Title> 
<sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
    <sld:Fill> 
        <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#00FFFFFF</sld:CssParameter>
    </sld:Fill>
    <sld:Stroke>
        <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#6a7c87</sld:CssParameter> 
        <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</sld:CssParameter>
        <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</sld:CssParameter>
    </sld:Stroke>
```

Comment: Where are you using this? Usually the WMS properties in the script of the application is where this is handled.

Comment: Show the relevant portion of the sld file you are using, especially the polygon fill opacity.

Comment: <sld:Name>Boundary</sld:Name>
            <sld:Title>Boundary</sld:Title>
            <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
              <sld:Fill>
                <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#00FFFFFF</sld:CssParameter>
              </sld:Fill>
              <sld:Stroke>
                <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#6a7c87</sld:CssParameter>
                <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</sld:CssParameter>
                <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</sld:CssParameter>
              </sld:Stroke> 
  here is the sld chunk for the polygon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to specify an opacity as a [`CssParameter`](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/reference/polygonsymbolizer.html#cssparameter)

```
<sld:Fill> 
   <sld:CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0</sld:CssParameter>
</sld:Fill>
```